# How do I override /theme/custom twig in my module to render input fields?

Tags: 8, theming, forms

I have a module that is building a form. I want to theme the form using twig within my module so it does not interfere with my theme/custom twigs.

My buildForm function is:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => $this->t('Name'),
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['#theme'] = 'custom_form';

  return $form;
}
```

I have set the theme for the form as `custom_form` and it works fine using this in my .module file:

```
function custom_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'custom_form' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
    ),
    'input' => array(
      'template' => 'input',
      'render element' => 'element',
    ),
  );
}
```

However the input fields are still being rendered using `input.html.twig` file in my /theme/custom theme folder.

I have created copied the twig template file using the same name and placed it in my custom_module folder however Drupal is still using my theme input.html.twig file.

How do I override this twig and use the input.html.twig file in my custom_module templates folder?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can have a template that has the same name as another template outside of the context of overriding the former.

Comment: Oh okay, how would I go about adding a custom twig template to theme the input fields?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after some intensive searching and looking at Drupal From API: Create a twig file for the theme, I called it `custom-input.html.twig` and place it in your custom_module templates folder. Then you tell Drupal about it using `hook_theme()` function:

```
function custom_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'custom_input' => array(
      'render element' => 'element',
    ),
  );
}
```

Lastly, in the buildForm function you say what theme will render the element like below:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => $this->t('Name'),
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#theme' => 'custom_input'
  );

  $form['#theme'] = 'custom_form';

  return $form;
}
```

This will tell Drupal to render the form input elements using the custom twig file you created.